# Bootstrap, panel-footer with text align-center horizontally and vertically jump out when resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel-footer with Bootstrap. I have centered the text inside it using the text-align property in the css and I have also centered it vertically (always in the css). Here is the css code:

```
.panel-footer{
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center; 
  color: #777;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This is the html page:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    Title and text - More text - Tel. +00 0000 00000  Fax. 0000 000 000 - <a href="privacy.php"><u>Privacy Policy</u></a> - <a href="cookie.php"><u>Cookie Policy</u></a>
</div>
```

When i resize the page the text jumps out. I have checked the code and the problem is the vertical alignment and is the following css code that cause it:

```
line-height: 80px;
```

Is there another way to vertically align the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you set the height of the div to 80px, try using another unit. For example `height: 20%;`

```css
.panel-footer{
   padding: 0 15px;
   height: 20%;
   line-height: 80px;
   text-align: center; 
   color: #777;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-color: #e7e7e7;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
    Title and text - More text - Tel. +00 0000 00000  Fax. 0000 000 000 - <a href="privacy.php"><u>Privacy Policy</u></a> - <a href="cookie.php"><u>Cookie Policy</u></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works on the desktop but has the same problem on the smartphone

Comment: sorry, it works also on the mobile. I refreshed the page and the cache and now it is ok also on the mobile. thanks. I vote for you answer. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I liked to help